# Whats the difference between complement and predicate?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused about the difference between complement and predicate.
Don't both function as what the subject is doing or what the subject is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complements "complete" grammatical structures.  They are essential to the structure and if they are omitted, the result is ungrammatical or is a different structure.  The opposite of a complement is a modifier, which is optional.

The predicate is the part of a sentence that follows the subject.

Subject complements are part of the predicate of a simple sentence with a linking verb like "is".  There are other complements in grammar. In a simple construction like

> The cat is happy.

the predicate is "is happy", and "happy" is the complement, as it is required for the grammar.

> The happy cat ate the fish.

> happy is a modifier.  The predicate is "ate the fish".

Comment: So, as the "is happy" and "happy" example above. I can conclude that complement is a part of predicate?

Comment: Yes, in that example.